# Why is lambda returning "<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" when I gave a positional argument?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, drop-down-menu, operating-system

```
def changedir(listbox):
    choice = varus.get()
    os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("C:/Users/haris/" + choice)
    directory = os.listdir("C:/Users/haris/" + choice)
    listbox.delete()
    directory = sorted(((os.stat(line).st_mtime, line) for line in directory if line.endswith('.zip')), reverse=1)
    for unixtime, line in directory:
        kws = datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtime)
        listbox.insert(tk.END, line, 'Date modified:', kws.date(), "\n")
```

So this is the function/command i am using for my tkinter project but for some reason, whenever I click the dropdown menu:

```
dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(window,
                         varus,
                         *certifiedpoop,
                         command=lambda:changedir(list))
```

I am always left with this error:

```
"<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"
```

What is going on???

Comment: `command=lambda:changedir(list))` gives *no positional arguments*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it seems to actually give a positional argument, seemingly the chosen value is passed to the function as the first argument, the simplest fix seems to just do `command=lambda _: changedir(list)`

Comment: `lambda:changedir(list)` means "an unnamed function (lambda) that *takes 0 arguments* (equivalently: has 0 parameters), calls `changedir(list)` regardless, and returns the result". When you interact with the `OptionMenu`, Tkinter will try to pass an argument to the `command` function that you assigned. Your code does not account for this argument. To understand the purpose of this argument, you should *read the documentation*.

Answer (score 4):

The callback of `command` option of `OptionMenu` expects an argument, the selected value, so you need to have an argument for the `lambda`.

Also you can pass this argument to `changedir()` so that you don't need to call `varus.get()` inside it:

```py
def changedir(listbox, choice):
    os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("C:/Users/haris/" + choice)
    directory = os.listdir("C:/Users/haris/" + choice)
    #listbox.delete()
    listbox.delete(0, 'end')
    directory = sorted(((os.stat(line).st_mtime, line) for line in directory if line.endswith('.zip')), reverse=1)
    for unixtime, line in directory:
        kws = datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtime)
        listbox.insert(tk.END, line, 'Date modified:', kws.date(), "\n")

...

dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(window,
                         varus,
                         *certifiedpoop,
                         command=lambda v:changedir(list, v))
```

Answer (score 2):

`tk.OptionMenu` passes the new value as a parameter to the function specified by `command`.

You can ignore it, but you must include it in the lambda definition: `lambda x: changedir(list))`

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is hinting that the lambda you pass as the `command` argument when building an `OptionMenu` widget takes an argument that is the selected item. You can choose to ignore it if you want, but it still needs to accept that argument.

For instance:

```
dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(window,
                         varus,
                         *certifiedpoop,
                         command=lambda selected: changedir(list))
```